# reproducing shiny using flexdashboard template

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

I borrowed this code below from the shinygallery and made some changes. Basically this uses `fluidPage`. I am interested in redoing the same thing using `flexdashboard` . I have gone through the [flexdashboard userguide](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/flexdashboard/using.html#value_boxes).
but the descriptions on that website are in some rmarkdown or sweave format ?? which I am not familiar with. So if I can see the flexdashboard version of this example  without the markdown or sweave then i can easily relate to different components and build on that. Any tips or pointers are appreciated folks.

```
library(shiny)
ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(
                mainPanel(
                 tabsetPanel(
                   tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("plot1"),plotOutput("plot2")),
                   tabPanel("Summary",verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
                  tabPanel("Table",DT::dataTableOutput("table"))
                   ))))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    plot(cars)
  })

  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    plot(iris)
  })

  output$summary <- renderPrint({
    summary(cars)
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(cars)
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I quickly put this together.

Not perfect. But it generally gets the job done (and I have to leave work, maybe I'll fine tune later tonight)

Note that I also had never come across `flexdashboard` before this post. I had used `shinydashboard` quite a bit, as well as RMarkdown, so this is definitely interesting. Not sure what `flexdashboard` will really add for me personally over and above `shinydashboard`, but I'm definitely going to play with it some more.

Anyway...

````
---
title: "Test App"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

Plot
=====================================  

row 
-------------------------------------


```{r}
library(shiny)
renderPlot({
  plot(cars)
})
```

row 
-------------------------------------

```{r}
renderPlot({
  plot(iris)
})
```   


Summary
=====================================     

```{r}   
renderPrint({
    summary(cars)
  })
```


Table
=====================================     

```{r}   
DT::renderDataTable({
    DT::datatable(cars)
  })
```
````

The one big issue being that while I'm calling row, I'm getting to the two plots on a single row instead of two different rows. I will play further.

Comment: thanks Andrew it worked for some reason the datatable is not opening for me in the last tab. I will dig into this.

Comment: You may need a `library(DT)` in setup section. But this does seem to be a problem [issue in flexdashboard](https://github.com/rstudio/flexdashboard/issues/28) which I see @missy has raised.