# How to use updateSelectInput in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'd like to change values of an inputbox based on another inputbox.

With R Shiny there is a method available: [updateSelectInput](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/updateSelectInput.html). But I'm not sure how to use it in flexdashboard.

Comment: you can't, flexdashboards aren't reactive.

Comment: Thanks @mtoto. Maybe I should rewrite my code in Shiny.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite late but also quite possible.

If this is your first `selectInput()`

```
raw_data <- mpg

selectInput(
  "manufacturer",
  label = "Select manufacturer",
  choices = c("All", sort(unique(raw_data$manufacturer)))
)
```

You can try either of these approaches. This one is overall less code:

```
renderUI({

  df <-
    raw_data %>%
    filter(
      manufacturer == input$manufacturer |
        input$manufacturer == "All"
    )

  selectInput(
    "model",
    label = "Select model",
    choices = c("All", sort(unique(df$model)))
  )

})
```

Or an `observeEvent()`. I think this one saves on performance as it only looks at one input, but it's not a huge difference.

```
selectInput(
    "model",
    label = "Select model",
    choices = c("All", sort(unique(raw_data$model)))
  )


observeEvent(input$manufacturer, {
  df <-
    raw_data %>%
    filter(
      manufacturer == input$manufacturer |
        input$manufacturer == "All"
    )

  updateSelectInput(
    session = session,
    inputId = "model",
    choices = c("All", sort(unique(df$model)))
  )
})
```